# SlidingMenu Width Not Correct

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

I'm using [jfeinstein1's slidingmenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in my project.  
I would like to have the sliding menu slide out to about 3/4 of the width of the screen.  According to the docs, this should be able to be accomplished using

```
setBehindWidth()
setBehindOffset()
```

But at the moment, the menu slides all the way to the right and covers the entire screen.  Below is my code:

```
public void setupMenu() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setBehindWidth(100);
    menu.setBehindOffset(100);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: folder ./values/dimens.xml may have the init config values mention by @tony

Comment: ugh, i'm so stupid it hurts. This method wasn't even being called because I had the invocation wrapped in an if() clause that was always returning false. All the suggestions worked. A shame I can only upvote one of you. Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a menu sliding from the right and simply call:

```
getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But this value 100 varies depending on screen size na?In devices with small screen size,its really ugly to see.I tried.Is there any way to set the width relative to the total screen width?For instance,35% of total screen width?

Answer (score 7):

The error is, that you choose both possibilities, so finally the last one wins:

```
menu.setBehindWidth(100);
menu.setBehindOffset(100);
```

.... and that is `setBehindOffset()` what causes your menu being moved until only 100 pixels are left. Using `setBehindWidth()` you would only see 100 pixels  of your menu.

So you need only this one:

```
menu.setBehindWidth(100);
```

Cheers!

**p.s** from the [documentation](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

`behindOffset` - a dimension representing the number of pixels that you want the above view to show when the behind view is showing. Default is 0.

`behindWidth` - a dimension representing the width of the behind view. Default is the width of the screen (equivalent to behindOffset = 0).

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to use both width and offset. Width is the width of the menu, offset is the width of the non-menu portion of the screen. Only one is meant to be used.

Comment: Currently, you will get an Exception if you use both